# read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get data from a sample api, I keep getting the error:

```
Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined.
```

Can anyone please tell me why I get the undefined error, do I need to bind to this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';

import Users from './components/Users.js';

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {users: []};
}


getUsers(){ 
     axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
.then(function (response) {
     this.setState({ users: response.data });
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
  });
}

componentDidMount(){
     this.getUsers();
}

render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
    </div>

      <Users data={this.state.users} />

  </div>
);
   }
  }

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `this` is a different object inside the scope of the callback. That's why it complains that `setState()` doesn't exist - it's the wrong object.

The easiest solution is a so-called *arrow function*. The reason this solves your issue is because arrow functions, unlike the traditional functions, do not bind the `this` object. As such, the `this` object inside the callback is the "correct" one and you can call `setState()`.

This is what the MDN documentation says on [**arrow functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An **arrow function expression** has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

and

> An arrow function does not create its own `this` context, so `this` has its original meaning from the enclosing context.

So your function would become:

```
getUsers(){ 
  axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then((response) => {
     this.setState({ users: response.data });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

The `catch` doesn't need changing since you are only logging to the console and don't use the `this` object - but I changed it anyway for consistency.